# Configure unrouted domains in nginx to go to a special folder?

Tags: nginx, configuration

I'm trying to configure my nginx to handle domains that are not routed so that they go to a special folder for unrouted domains, instead the unrouted domain loads from my main domain's folder.

An example:

```
http {
    include mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;
    sendfile on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name somedomain.com;
        root C:/web_root/somedomain.com;
        index index.html index.htm;
    }
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name localhost;
        root C:/web_root/unrouted;
        index index.html index.htm;
    }
}
```

So I want all visitors who try to set an A record to my server to go to the special unrouted folder.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

The default server (that is where there is no explicit `server_name` match) is the first `server` container with a matching port. Unless you specify the default server by using the `default_server` keyword on the appropriate `listen` directive:

```
listen 80 default_server;
```

Take a look at [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html).

Comment: Thank you, it seems I was just misreading it and putting `servername 80 default_server;` and leaving `listen 80;` as is.